# How to apply Count on multiple distinct columns and use Having clause

Tags: sql, oracle, count, indexing, distinct

I would like to do something like this , but getting an error please suggest some good methods?

```
select A,B,C, count(Distinct A,B,C)
from table_name 
group by A,B,C 
having count(Distinct A,B,C) > 1
```

Basically i have an index on the columns(A,B,C), and some rows doesnt have this unique combination set, So I'm trying a query similar to identify the rows which disobeys the unique constraint. PLease let me know if there is a best way

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you group by these columns then you already only get those unique records and then you can use `count(*)` to get how many duplicates you have

```
select A,B,C, count(*) 
from table_name 
group by A,B,C 
HAVING count(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 3):

What @jurgend said is right, and you can further find the exact rows (I'm assuming there are more fields to look at, including maybe a PK) by doing

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
WHERE (A,B,C) IN ( 
    SELECT A, B, C 
    FROM table_name
    GROUP BY A, B, C
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

A `Tuple IN` list query works in Oracle, although not all other DBMS.

Comment: It woks in postgresql, i just test it. tank you.